# What is a functional way to create a new collection from an object?

Tags: javascript, lodash

What is a  way to create this collection from this object which doesn't mutate. Can I use lodash?

```
var obj = {Express: 2, Long_Haul: 1, Short_Haul: 1}

let collection = []

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => collection.push({method: key, quantity: 
obj[key]}))

// output:
// [ { method: 'Express', quantity: 2 },{ method: 'Long_Haul', quantity: 1 },{ method: 'Short_Haul', quantity: 1 } ]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `.map` to turn an array of the `.entries` of the object into an array of objects with the desired property names:

```js
var obj = {Express: 2, Long_Haul: 1, Short_Haul: 1}
const collection = Object.entries(obj)
  .map(([method, quantity]) => ({ method, quantity }));
console.log(collection);
```

While you *can* use Lodash to achieve this, there's no need for it, built-in methods work just fine.

Comment: Destructuring really shines with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in function from js, if the js engine you're using doesn't provide those functions, you can use lodash.

```js
let obj = {Express: 2, Long_Haul: 1, Short_Haul: 1}
let collection = _.map(_.toPairs(obj), function(arr) {
  return { method: arr[0], quantity: arr[1] };
});

console.log(collection);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in lodash that uses a chain of [`toPairs`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#toPairs), [`map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map) with a partially applied [`zipObject`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#zipObject).

```
const collection = _(obj).toPairs()
    .map(_.partial(_.zipObject, ['method', 'quantity']))
    .value();
```

```js
var obj = {Express: 2, Long_Haul: 1, Short_Haul: 1};

const collection = _(obj).toPairs()
 .map(_.partial(_.zipObject, ['method', 'quantity']))
 .value();
  
console.log(collection);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution use lodash

```
const obj = {Express: 2, Long_Haul: 1, Short_Haul: 1}
const collection = _.map(obj, (value, key) => ({method: key, quantity: value}))
```

---

The *map* function will invoke *iteratee* with *key*. Use one `_.map` function will get job done.

> `_.map(collection, [iteratee=_.identity])`
>
> > Creates an array of values by running each element in collection thru iteratee. The iteratee is invoked with three arguments:
> >     (value, index|key, collection).
>
> https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map